# JW Player HLS playback: "Playlist could not be loaded: No playable sources found"

Tags: javascript, html, jwplayer6

I am trying to play an HLS stream on JW Player 6.10.

Here is my source code:

```
    <html>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">jwplayer.key="keyyy";</script>
<div id="my-video"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("my-video").setup({
file: "http://server/hls/playlist.m3u8",
width: "580",
height: "370",
primary: "html5",
autostart: "true",
provider: "hls",
androidhls:true}
);
</script>
</html>
```

I only get this message on playback: "Playlist could not be loaded: No playable sources found". The stream works here without any problems: http://demo.jwplayer.com/stream-tester/

Thanks for your help!